# 100% width not working in IE or Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a website that is driving me crazy.  Specifically, I have an image of a curve at the very top of the page that I want to resize to always fill the width of the screen.

This works great in Firefox and Opera but I can't seem to get it to work in IE or Chrome.

I've got the following CSS applied to the image through a class:

```
img.top{
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 35px;
  top: 10;
  left: 0;
}
```

but even with the 100vw to use the view window, the image is using the display width of my monitor as a minimum rather than the width of my browser.  Testing with IE 11, FF 51.0.1, and Opera 43.0.2442

You can find the site at http://stats-jf.fin.gov.nt.ca/

To give a minimal verifiable page ... http://stats-jf.fin.gov.nt.ca/index2.html has virtually all of the code stripped out except the curve and a few other elements to show the impact.  "Working Properly" the curve should fit the browser window down to 998px wide and "Test Page" should always remain below the Bear logo.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: That minimal verifiable doesnt really help because the page elements are what cause the overflow which makes the vertical scrollbar occur which is the source of the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B wanted a minimal verifiable ... so I gave him one.  I knew it wouldn't help but that's what he required ...

Comment: @NWT_Bob, it's not what I require. Those are standard guidelines for this site.

Comment: A primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to serve as a reference source. But what happens to your link once your problem is solved? It becomes useless as an illustration of the problem, and this entire post loses value. That's why the guidelines ask for the problem to be reproduced in the question itself.

Comment: @Michael_B ... ok, those are the guidelines but you still gave me a -2 on the question (and -5 on my reputation) which is a pretty harsh way of encouraging people to use minimal verifiable posts.

Comment: It's nothing personal. But I retracted my down vote nonetheless.

Comment: *... and keep in mind I'm not the only other person on this site ;-)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the following to the containing table:

```
<table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0px;">
```

and remove the width:100vw; from your image:

```
img.top{
  width: 100%;  
  height: 35px;  
  top: 10px;  
  left: 0;
}
```

you also forgot to state the unit you are using in the top: property. i've set it to 10px.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried adding that to the table, tr, td, and even the img tags ... none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Comment: sorry, quite right. You need to remove the width:100vw; from the image too.

This works because the border-spacing was using the browser defaults which differ from browser to browser. Using a reset.css can fix this.

The image is being set to 100% of the viewport width (Scrollbar and all) so when the image went under the vertical scrollbar, it necessitated a horizontal scrollbar to show the hidden portion of the image. setting the image to width:calc(100vw - 20px) would also get around this issue but 'calc' is not as well supported by older browsers.

Comment: I removed the 100vw on the image and it's still responding the same way.  The text ("Test Page" on the minimal version or "Welcome to NWT Job Futures" on the real version) isn't staying in line with the bear logo as it does in FF because the image isn't resizing to less than the width of the display.  When I stretch really wide (3000 or 4000 px) everything stretches great.  But shrinking doesn't work as expected.

Comment: its no the display. 100VW is 100% of the browser window (whatever size monitor its on, whatever its resized too).
If the problem you are having is that you get a horizontal scrollbar whenever you hit 1000px its because you are using a table for your layout. 
Its not really clear what the problem, can you explain in more detail?

Just to clarify, your table has a defined style to have a width of 998px.

Comment: The goal was to have the curve go all the way across the screen regardless of the width of the browser.  Below that, within an object 998px wide would be the content for the site ... so within the 2nd row of the table I put an interior table that is 998px wide.  The remainder of the page (in the test case where I have "Test Page") is also supposed to be 998px wide and thus line up with the elements in the 2nd row of the site.  In the full version of the site, there are 2 additional lines that go the full width of the browser before the main content begins.

Comment: I cant reproduce. The example link sent in the OP is behaving exactly as you described the desired outcome on my machine. The curve is full width, the rest of the content centrally aligned at 998px.

Comment: @AnthonyCregan ... using what browser?  It works perfectly for me in FF or Opera ... but not IE or Chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136784/discussion-between-nwt-bob-and-anthony-cregan).

Comment: I appreciate the help @AnthonyCregan ... wish we could have solved it but the same browser doing different things on different machines is a hard one to solve!

Answer (score 0):

At Anthony's suggestion I moved the curve into it's own  which solved the initial problem but created a new one.

The table below wasn't stretching to the full width in all browsers because it had a combination of width="100%" and style attributes ... but did NOT have a width attribute within the style.  As soon as I added a width: 100% into the style for the table ... the problem was resolved in all browsers.

**So watch out for mixing old html styling with new** ... doing so can create unusual results.

I know, I'm preaching to the choir!